# "vue-cli-service test:unit " runs succesfully; but npm exits err code 1 ELIFECYCLE

Tags: vue.js, npm, jestjs, vue-cli

I'm trying to run `npm run test:unit` and the true error seems to be `test:unit: Failed to exec test:unit script` from the npm debug.log. Yet the script DOES run and execute without issue.

I'm a little new to NPM + Node so I'm struggling with this behavior.  When I run `npm run test:unit` ( `"test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"`  in Package.json) I get this output:

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 file obsolete, 0 total
Time:        1.208s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cheatsheet@0.1.0 test:unit: `vue-cli-service test:unit`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the cheatsheet@0.1.0 test:unit script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/max/.npm/_logs/2020-03-26T18_16_36_155Z-debug.log
```

**Expected Result**
The tests should just pass, I shouldn't see NPM/Node crash.

Running `./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service test:unit` I get just the test and Jest output.  Everything works as expected.  So what is going wrong with my setup?

**Attempted Resolution**

- reinstalled node_modules
- updated npm
- updated to node:stable
- reinstall nvm (node version manager) and updated
- attempted to add extra debug flags to vue-cli-service

```
npm_debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/max/.nvm/versions/node/v13.11.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/max/.nvm/versions/node/v13.11.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test:unit'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v13.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest:unit', 'test:unit', 'posttest:unit' ]
5 info lifecycle cheatsheet@0.1.0~pretest:unit: cheatsheet@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle cheatsheet@0.1.0~test:unit: cheatsheet@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle cheatsheet@0.1.0~test:unit: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle cheatsheet@0.1.0~test:unit: PATH: /home/max/.nvm/versions/node/v13.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/max/cheatsheet_project/cheatsheet/node_modules/.bin:/home/max/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/max/.pyenv/shims:~/.pyenv/bin:/home/max/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin:/home/max/.nvm/versions/node/v13.11.0/bin:/home/max/.rbenv/shims:/home/max/.rbenv/bin:/home/max/workspace/go/bin:/home/max/.cargo/bin:/home/max/.cargo/bin:/home/max/bin:/home/max/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
9 verbose lifecycle cheatsheet@0.1.0~test:unit: CWD: /home/max/cheatsheet_project/cheatsheet
10 silly lifecycle cheatsheet@0.1.0~test:unit: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service test:unit' ]
11 silly lifecycle cheatsheet@0.1.0~test:unit: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle cheatsheet@0.1.0~test:unit: Failed to exec test:unit script
13 verbose stack Error: cheatsheet@0.1.0 test:unit: `vue-cli-service test:unit`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/max/.nvm/versions/node/v13.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/max/.nvm/versions/node/v13.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid cheatsheet@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/max/cheatsheet_project/cheatsheet
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-91-generic
17 verbose argv "/home/max/.nvm/versions/node/v13.11.0/bin/node" "/home/max/.nvm/versions/node/v13.11.0/bin/npm" "run" "test:unit"
18 verbose node v13.11.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error cheatsheet@0.1.0 test:unit: `vue-cli-service test:unit`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the cheatsheet@0.1.0 test:unit script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: what does the complete log say? npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/max/.npm/_logs/2020-03-26T18_16_36_155Z-debug.log

Comment: This sometimes occurs because an asynchronous bit of code threw an error after the test technically finished. So, your test may actually be failing even though it says it passed. Would need a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to confirm that though.

Comment: @c0de added the NPM debug log.  I can't figure out if I should look at the script or NPM.  `Failed to exec test:unit script` makes it sounds like the npm script did not execute at all.  When it did.

Running ./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service test:unit from the node_modules/bin is successful without issue so I'm baffled by the failure when running it as a script.

Comment: So apparently I have to read more about Jest...

I noticed the `Snapshots:   1 file obsolete, 0 total`

And took the advice of the stdout and reran jest like so:
`./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service test:unit -u`


This seems to have resolved the issue.  `npm run test:unit` now runs as expected...  Cannot explain it without looking at Jest + Vue-CLI more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service test:unit -u` fixed this.  This is the shorthand command for `jest --updatesnapshot`.

> Since we just updated our component to point to a different address, it's reasonable to expect changes in the snapshot for this component. Our snapshot test case is failing because the snapshot for our updated component no longer matches the snapshot artifact for this test case.
>
> To resolve this, we will need to update our snapshot artifacts. You can run Jest with a flag that will tell it to re-generate snapshots...
>   - From [Snapshot Testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing).

Observed the error about snapshots:

> Snapshots:   1 file obsolete, 0 total

Unsure why this caused the NPM error but `-u` cleared it and I haven't seen it again.

Comment: the output should've showed you that there was an obsolete snapshot followed by a message with how to update. but glad you were able to fix it!